# New Tag for Thornwatch?

Tags: support, tagging

Can we get a tag for the Thornwatch boardgame?
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/159011/thornwatch

[Thornwatch - How does paying for Hero Actions work?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/43514/316)

Answer (score 1):

Added the tag.  Tags will get fixed pretty quickly around here.  If needed, you can always flag the question.

Comment: Figured it would, is there an "untaggable game" tag? And how much rep do you need to add tags again? On the app so can't view the Faq...

Comment: @deworde 150 on this site

Comment: Huh, weird, maybe because I'm using the app, but I typed Thornwatch in a bunch of times while trying to submit the question and it didn't take.

Comment: @deworde SE apps restrict the selection to existing tags only, though [there's a bug to create new tags on Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278640/tag-field-can-be-input-freely-when-editing-a-question-on-android-app)